# How to use sass in a simple html file without including cdn js, and send html files in mail to someone

Tags: html, sass, email-attachments

I have an html file and I want to use sass in that html template. I want to send that html over the email as an attachment. So how all the sass can be send using in html file.

My main concern is to how we can create a html template using sass and send it to someone on email attachment.

Answer (score 2):

Sass is a CSS preprocessor, so it can not be read by browsers directly. You compile your Sass to CSS and then include it in your HTML-file.

Example:

You have a styles.scss and compile it to styles.css.
If you want to have it all in one file:
Add a  tag to your HTML-Head and copy the content of styles.css into it.

Comment: There are many tools, even web-apps, that can compile Sass to CSS. First one I found: https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: Thanks @dustin-we, so my question is, Is their any way which i can include the sass file in our html template and send it to someone, where they can install in locally and run the project, & lastly what i need to add in the project file and how i can add.

Comment: Do they need to review the Sass-code? Or just look at the HTML-file?

Comment: Yes they might review the sass code so i need to send him including the scss file.

Comment: Not if you want to keep it simple, I think. You could just ZIP it, but then they would have to compile it manually, since you don't want to use CDN JS